# Add vita at the end of dissertation

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, header-footer

I am writing my dissertation in LaTeX and I need to add my Vita at the end. Can you please help in defining the structure.

My requirements are:

1. 'Vita' needs to appear in the 'table of contents' as other chapters.
2. On vita page there is no chapter number and starts as usual page.

If I want to include the following statement in main text file, How to I need to define `\printvita`?

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Vita}
\printvita
```

Comment: It seems like `\printvita` should be `\chapter*{Vita}` and placed *before* `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Vita}`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it. Please not that the `lipsum` package and `\lipsum` command are for the example only (it prints dummy text). You can replace them by your actual vita.

I am including the vita automatically in the table of contents so you don't need to write the command yourself every time.

The actual code for the vita is between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (which you can remove if you put it in personal a `.sty` or `.cls` file), and the end-user only needs to write `\vita{...}` in the preamble, like you would do with `\author` or `\title`. You can write several paragraphs of vita.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\vita{\long\def\@vita}
\def\printvita{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Vita}
    \@afterheading\@vita
}
\makeatother

\vita{\lipsum[1]}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[2]

\printvita

\end{document}
```

Note: I was not exactly sure what you wanted, so I chose to make it look like a new chapter, except without the heading. If this is not exactly what you required, please let me know and I will update it.

Comment: The following commands worked for me.         \thispagestyle{plain}   and 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Vita}